# Python pandas: Taking values from one database, Assigning them another value and replacing them in a 2nd database

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

Dataframe 1:

```
userId  movieId rating  timestamp
0   1   2   3.5 1112486027
1   1   29  3.5 1112484676
2   1   32  3.5 1112484819
3   1   47  3.5 1112484727
4   1   50  3.5 1112484580
```

Dataframe 2:

```
   movieId    title                    genres
0    1        Toy Story (1995)         Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy
1    2        Jumanji (1995)           Adventure|Children|Fantasy
2    3        Grumpier Old Men(1995)   Comedy|Romance
3    4        Waiting to Exhale (1995) Comedy|Drama|Romance
4    5  Father of the Bride Part II (1995)  Comedy
```

Both Dataframes don't have the same number of rows. I want to replace the movieId numbers in Dataframe 1 by the names of the movies they represent from dataframe 2. How to do so?

I tried the following code:

```
s = data2['title']
while i <= 131261:
    array[i]= data2.index([data2['movieId'] == i])
    i = i + 1

while pos<= len(array) - 1:

    data3 = data['movieId'].replace([data['movieId'] == i],'[data2[pos]]')
```

But it showed the following error:

```
TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-c6bed86d99a5> in <module>()
1 s = data2['title']
2 while i <= 131261:
----> 3     array[i]= data2.index([data2['movieId'] == i])
      4     i = i + 1
      5 

TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable
```

What is my mistake and can someone suggest in  better ways?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`:

```
df1['movieId'] = df1['movieId'].map(df2.set_index('movieId')['title'])
```

Comment: I did try that however it filled all the movieId values with Nan. Can someone suggest any improvements.

Comment: @ASHUTOSHBBHATT - Problem is not same types of both columns, so need convert to same: `df1['movieId'] = df1['movieId'].astype(int)` and `df2['movieId'] = df2['movieId'].astype(int)` before `map`.